# Best scalable model for a website serving millions of users everyday

Tags: nosql, webserver, scalable

I want to develop a website that will serve millions of pages everyday including the mobile devices. Site will have strong social features and thus would require lots of reads/writes. It will also suggest things to users based on their social behaviors (likes, dislikes etc) and their friends' behaviors. After considering many elements I have come up with

NoSQL (MongoDB or Cassandra) Database. Not sure which one is the right one.
memcached
Varnish or squid for http acceleration
php and python (Not sure if php is that scalable)
nginx or Apache web server

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

There are NoSQL databases that has an integrated web service that can handle much more web requests per second (including database transaction time) compared to traditional web services requesting data from an external data source. Using this kind of solution increases the performance, save a lot of time in implementation and simplify scaling your website.

The recommendation depends on how you plan on implementing the solution: a server side rendering solution or a client rendered solution? Will you have any MVVM style implementation making the communication talkative? Also what server side environment do you have in mind? Microsoft/Linux?

Take a look at Starcounter database that has a web server component integrated into the database engine and see if that could help you.